Aspose.Word How to convert a Docx document with IF condition into HTML using C#
I have a problem with condition IF in conversion docx to html with Aspose.Word.
I have model document for a direct mail with condition :

{IF 0=0 "Mail OK" "Mail KO"}

And it don't work when I want do display the merged text in HTML editor.
Know you if is there a solution to properly generate the body of an email (in html) from a Word document with if condition?
Thanks
Ela

Do you need to preserve IF field condition in the output HTML? Unfortunately, Aspose.Words does not support preserving IF field conditions in HTML. You should note that HTML format model is very different from MS Word document model and it is impossible to preserve all features of MS Word document in HTML and vice versa.

Yes, I need to preserve IF field condition in the output HTML. Thank you very much for your answer, that's what I thought. I will think about another solution.
